# What's the best way to define a particular number with special characters in a database django

Tags: django, database, django-models, model

I have a specific requirement for a Django model field, essentially I want to create this type of series:

0025-0007

Essentially 4 integer fields, one character, and 4 integer fields thereafter, I don't need an auto-increment as the number changes, is there anything available in Django already that handles such fields, ideally something with automatic validation?

```
@login_required
def close_lead(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        deal_form = NewDealForm(request.POST)

        if deal_form.is_valid():
            deal_form.save()
            id = request.GET.get('project_id', '')
            obj = Leads.objects.get(project_id=id)
            obj.status = "Closed"
            obj.save(update_fields=['status'])
            ## Changing the Forecast Table Entry
            forecast = LeadEntry.objects.filter(lead_id=id)
            for i in forecast:
                m = i
                m.stage = "Deal"
                m.save(update_fields=['stage'])
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully updated the status from open to Close')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error updating your Form')

    id = request.GET.get('project_id', '')
    keys = Leads.objects.select_related().get(project_id=id)
    form_dict = {'project_id': keys.project_id,
                     'agent': keys.agent,
                     'client': keys.point_of_contact,
                     'company': keys.company,
                     'service': keys.services,
                     'licenses': keys.expected_licenses,
                     'country_d': keys.country
                     }

    form = NewDealForm(initial=form_dict)

    return render(request,
                  "account/close_lead.html",
                  {'form': form})
```

```
## HTML 
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Close Lead{% endblock %}
{% block content %}


  <h1>Close a Lead</h1>
<div class="Myform">
  <form method="post" id="close-lead">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.project_id|as_crispy_field }}
                  {{ form.agent|as_crispy_field }}
                  {{ form.sales_order|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.company|as_crispy_field }}
                  {{ form.country_d|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.client|as_crispy_field }}

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.service|as_crispy_field }}
                  {{ form.revenue|as_crispy_field }}
                  {{ form.comments|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  {{ form.licenses|as_crispy_field }}

              </div>
            </div>


           </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Create Deal">
  </form>



{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a validator and work with a `CharField` and a [**`RegexValidator`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#regexvalidator):

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(
        max_length=9,
        validators=[RegexValidator(r'\d{4}.\d{4}', 'The value should be four digits, a character and four digits')]
    )
```

If the separator between the four digits is always a hyphen, you use `r'\d{4}-\d{4}'` instead.

Comment: Willem, quick question, the validator doesn't seem to work, if I enter any other value, I actually get an error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'form' referenced before assignment, to me it seems like the form.valid in my views doesn't accept the value, but I get full error in the HTML page

Comment: @FranciscoColina: this means that you *use* the `form` variable, before you assigned a value, for example before `form = SomeForm()`, you use `form.is_valid()`.

Comment: I changed the logic slightly, and now I'm getting the 'Error Updating your form'), which means that the form validation is working, but I don't see this message: 'The value should be four digits, a character and four digits'

Comment: @FranciscoColina: where do you see that message? How do you render the form? Can you edit the question with the view, and template?

Comment: Willem, thanks, if you have a look at the view, I'm sending an error message if the form is not validated, I somehow thought that the validator in the models will be automatically use by the form, but perhaps I'm missing that part

Comment: @FranciscoColina: you should *not* create a new form if the form is invalid. You only should create a new form if the method is GET. The logic in the tail of the view function thus needs to be indented properly.